# Routing issues on Ruby on Rails 4.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I am trying to perform destroy action n windows 7, I am receiving:

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/default.css" for ::1 at 2016-06-20 13:52:53 +0530
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/default.css"):
```

and

```
Started GET "/javascripts/default.js" for ::1 at 2016-06-20 13:52:59 +0530
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js"):
```

Comment: Please post more information. Like what you're trying to do, where and what error you're getting with log information.

Comment: I am trying to perform the destroy action in ruby 4.2.6 , but it is not deleting and rather showing routing error shown above ! let me know what more you want !

Comment: does application.css / application.js contains path of default.css / default.js  and actual file doesn't exists?

Comment: does the DELETE even fire? show the line that is calling the destroy /delete method.

Comment: Please add jQuery js into you application.

Answer (score 1):

use "application" instead of "default" in 
    views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the request, i.e. `delete`, is irrelevant.

**Edit:=================**
Your error is due to the fact that your `stylesheet_link_tag` on the page `views/layouts/application.html.erb` looks something like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "default", media: "all" %>
```

but there is no file by the name of `default.css` in `assets/stylesheets`--presumably the default file `application.css` contains the manifest for the css files.
**====================**

The rails `asset pipeline` combines all the css files listed in the manifest file `assets/stylesheets/application.css` into one big file, minimizes it, then sends the single css file to the browser when a view is loaded.  The same thing happens for all your js files.  To properly link to your single, minimized css file and  your single minimized js file,  the `views/layouts/application.html.erb` file should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>  #<****HERE
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>             #<****HERE
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>


<div>
  <%= yield %>
</div>

<%= debug params %>
<%= debug session[:allowed] %>

</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads in your browser, you will see requests in your server window like:

```
Started GET "/assets/cats.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-20 04:06:19 -0600


Started GET "/assets/cats.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-20 04:06:19 -0600
```

You ***can*** use the path:

```
/stylesheets/default.css
```

in your `stylesheet_link_tag` if the file:

```
public/stylesheets/default.css
```

exists.  According to the [rails asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), you also have to add:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

to `config/application.rb`--but I find that is not needed for development, so it's probably required for production.

The server window does not show a request for a css file located in the `public/` directory, but you can open a web inspector and examine the network activity and see that your browser does send the request.

Comment: we I have changed application to default  :-
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "default", media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "default", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
otherwise it is giving  error page showing given object or method is not defined

Comment: @SIDDHARTHJAIN,  The name of the file--"application.css" or "default.css"--is irrelevant as long as it matches the stylesheet_link_tag in `views/layouts/applicatons.html.erb`.  Same for the js file.

Comment: @SIDDHARTHJAIN, If I use "default" in `stylesheet_link_tag()` but the css manifest file's path is actually `assets/stylesheets/application.css`, then I get the same error you did.  If I change the name of `assets/stylesheets/application.css` to `assets/stylesheets/default.css`, then no routing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the method for the delete action to be performed, because i think if you don't provide the exact method , which in case of your's is DELETE it would redirect to some other paths. If you can provide the syntax you are using for this , it will be more helpful to resolve the issue. For eg:-

<%= link_to '', your_action_path(object.id),:class=>"btn btn-danger fa fa-trash-o fa-1x",:style=>"margin-top:4px",:confirm =>'Are you sure',:method => :delete %>